# Accessing variable and changing it in another Python script

Tags: python

I have a python script `surfactant.py`. I am importing this script and printing `J` as shown below. But I want to modify this `J` without opening `surfactant.py`. How do I do it?

Initially, `J= [2, 6, 9, 10]` in `surfactant.py`. I want to modify this list to `J= [2, 6, 9]`.

```
import surfactant as surf
J=surf.J
print("J=",J)
```

Comment: What do you mean "opening"? Also, what do you mean with modifying exactly? Can you describe what changes you want to make?

Comment: I have provided detail about the modification.

Comment: Are you wanting to modify `J` during the runtime of `surfactant`? Or are you just wanting to modify it during the runtime of the script you're importing it into? Please provide a bit more information about what you are doing, as this smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I want to modify ```J``` during runtime of ```surfactant.py```.

Comment: Do you want this change to be permanent? Then you need to rewrite `surfactant.py`

Comment: Yes I want it to be permanent.